# FB.XFBML.parse() fails during rendering

Tags: meteor, meteor-helper

I've been trying to execute `FB.XFBML.parse();` to reload all Facebook social plugins. I can successfully execute it in `Template.sample.events({})` but not in `Template.sample.onRendered()` or `Template.sample.rendered` as I am getting an error saying that `FB` is undefined. My code is as follows:

```
Template.sample.onRendered(function() {
  FB.XFBML.parse();
});
```

OR

```
Template.sample.rendered = function() {
  FB.XFBML.parse();
}
```

How can I execute FB.XFBML.parse(); every time a template is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrapped the method with a try-catch block. Noticed that for `rendered` is being called multiple times. The first pass fails saying FB is undefined while the succeeding passes succeeds.

```
Template.sample.rendered = function() {
    try {
        FB.XFBML.parse();
    } catch (e) {
        // Will normally crash but succeeding execution will be successful
    }
}
```